# What is the most efficient way to store the data in my case?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I recently want to store millions of key/value pairs on hard disk. The data is like this,

1. "Keys" are all strings, with various lengths (can use their hashes if needed)
2. "Values" are all arrays of integers. And the arrays are all of the same length (say 500) and wont change anymore.

And I would like to search some of the values by keys very often through python or R. What data bases should I use in terms of searching speed and storage occupation? (for example, mongodb, hdf5 or sql?) Thanks!

Comment: Your question is [**off topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and too broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you're only dealing with `key-value` pairs then `Mongo` should work out best for you. However, if you'll still be needing some of the RDBMS features, check out for `PostgreSQL 9.5/9.6` since recent version of `Postgre` does support JSON flawlessly but not as good as `Mongo` does.

Also, if `big-data` is one of your concerns, consider using some caching using `Redis` with any of the databases listed above.

Comment: Thanks! The data here are all arrays of integers with fixed length. Is Mongo most efficient in storing this? What if I want to change some of the values in the array?

Comment: Its basically `CRUD`, ain't it? So all databases do it. Databases are really really important for an application's long run. Give yourself plenty of time on RESEARCH because you want everything to be stable later. Consider benchmarking every database you consider. Maybe you'll also have to make revisions to the database structure and design multiple times to meet optimality.